# What is actually a HTTP request?

Tags: forms, http, window.location

I am wondering what are the occurrences of an HTTP request actually. I know that when you use AJAX then you send an HTTP request. However what is the case when you simply perform a window.location or send data through a form. Does an HTTP request occurs in those cases as well?

Comment: "Does an HTTP request occurs in those cases as well"? Yes. I suggest you open your F12 console in your browser, go to the network tab and look at all the HTTP requests going on. I just clicked the StackOverflow home page and a total of 38 HTTP requests occurred

Comment: I see, so even an image request from your project's public directory is an HTTP request? is that also located on the server?

Comment: It's requested from the server but often it is cached locally. If you click on an image request in our console, the status code has something like `200 OK (from disk cache)`. The URL is a web URL but the actual asset is taken from local disk cause that's where it's caches. Keep in mind that most local client access is blocked from browsers unless it's in a managed capacity (i.e. cookies etc.)

Comment: You will learn a lot from the F12 console and it is also _critical_ for debugging any web apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**H**yper**T**ext **T**ransfer **P**rotocol is a communication protocol used in a wide variety of IT communications. It's really just a set of steps and rules that 2 devices use when exchanging information. These steps are numbered in 3 digits. The most famous one being 404, not found (referring to the hyperlink).
The WWW is a great example of this. If you look at the address bar of the browser that you are currently viewing this in, you will find "https" at the start of the link. The S stands for "secure", but otherwise, this basically indicates that the website you are currently viewing was retrieved through an HTTP request.
HTML forms typically send information through HTTP requests as well.

AJAX performs HTTP requests, yes, but that's hardly the most noteworthy aspect of AJAX. What makes AJAX interesting, is that it allows webapplications to run an HTTP request while remaining in an HTML document, and through Javascript, update the HTML document accordingly.

I would recommend looking up the status codes used in an HTTP request to understand the process that occurs when an HTTP request is initiated.
https://httpstatuses.com/

This should help you understand the nature and purpose of the protocol.